# How to query a column with json data type column that has a single quote

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named event which is a json data type and the value is something like this

```
{
  "formcomponentsmap['order'].city": "this is a city"
}
```

I am trying to access it like this `event->>"$.formcomponentsmap['order'].city"` but it returns an error of

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

What is the best way to get the value of that column.
I should get the value of "this is a city"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put the key in double quotes and escape the single quotes with backslashes, the following will work:

```
event->>'$".formcomponentsmap[\'order\'].city"'
```